# HandleServiceArgs null pointer exception ~ Android Service

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception

This program detects if user change the root access status. User define any time period. In this time period, it controls the rootaccess status. When I start the service, it gives an error. Actually it was working before but now its not. I couldn't find any null variable. 
I open Application Manager on device and look to running services. It says 'starting again' for this service.

RootAccess Service;

```
public class RootAccessService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId) {

    Bundle b= intent.getExtras();
    if(b != null){

        context = getApplicationContext();
        helper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        timer = new Timer();
        handler = new Handler();
        inventoryId = 1;
        periodSelection = b.getString("period");

        parts = periodSelection.split(" ");
        min = Long.parseLong(parts[0]);
        time = min * 60 * 1000;
        killMe = false;
        handler.postDelayed(check, time);
    }

}


private final Runnable check = new Runnable() { 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(killMe)
            return;
        Start();
        handler.postDelayed(check, time);
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Stop();
    super.onDestroy();

}

public void Start(){
    //do smtg
}

public void Stop(){
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(check);
    killMe = true;
    helper.close();
}
```

}

```
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.cryptodlp.RootAccessService@41de6fd0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2553)

12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:134)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at com.example.cryptodlp.RootAccessService.onStart(RootAccessService.java:49)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2536)
12-18 14:02:24.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18004):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched this problem and I used AlarmManager and start the service with AlarmManager.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RootAccessService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), Integer.parseInt(parts[0])*60*1000, pintent);
```